# Make ggparcoord interactive

Tags: r, ggplot2, interactive, ggally

I would like to have the user select from a group of pulldown values for the order in the ggparcoord function. How can I do that?  In general, I'm a little stumped about adding interactivity to visualizations in R.  I know, I'm a newbie.

I've tried a few things but it was genuinely just guessing

Comment: Could you please share some code you have tried and reproducible data?